# Hide a systemd service for non-root users

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-18.04

I have a custom service entry in systemd on Ubuntu 18.04. The main executable is a script which creates some processes:

```
foor@bar:~$ systemctl status XXXXXX.service
● XXXXXX.service - XXXXXX
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/XXXXXX.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-11-19 14:18:39 UTC; 25min ago
  Process: 4210 ExecStart=/usr/bin/XXXXXX (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 43 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/XXXXXX.service
           ├─3383 python3 XXXXXX
           ├─4168 python3 XXXXXX
           ├─4619 hostapd -B XXXXXX
           ├─4623 hostapd -B XXXXXX
           ├─4639 wpa_supplicant XXXXXX
           ├─4649 wpa_supplicant XXXXXX
           ├─4659 wpa_supplicant XXXXXX
           ├─4669 wpa_supplicant XXXXXX
           ├─4679 wpa_supplicant -B XXXXXX
           ├─4699 wpa_supplicant -B XXXXXX
           ├─4709 wpa_supplicant -B XXXXXX
           ├─4719 wpa_supplicant -B XXXXXX
           ├─4798 dhcpd XXXXXX
           ├─4802 XXXXXX
           ├─4806 XXXXXX
          ....
```

systemd.service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=XXXXXX
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/root/
ExecStart=+XXXXXX
ExecStop=XXXXXX
Restart=on-failure
KillMode=process
TimeoutStartSec=180

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The service has educational purposes and I want to hide these processes from the student, so they cannot see them e.g. `ps aux`. Because this can give them some context which is unwanted in the challenge.

I tried with `mount -o remount,rw,hidepid=2 /proc` but it causes issues with other things in the setup because it hides all processes. So, I need some solution which hides only the listed processes with `systemctl status XXXXXX.service`.